# Signature of matrix associated with q

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, quadratic-forms

> For $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, let $q(x_1, x_2) = x_1^2
> + 2\alpha x_1x_2 + \dfrac{1}{2}2x_2^2$, for $(x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R^2}$.Find all values of $\alpha$ for which the signature of $q$ is 1.

The matrix associated with the quadratic form is $\begin{bmatrix} 1& \alpha\\\alpha&\frac12\end{bmatrix}$. To find the signature we reduce it to a diagonal form by simultaneous row and column transformations as  $$\begin{bmatrix} 1& \alpha\\\alpha&\frac12\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow[C_2\rightarrow C_2-\alpha C_1]{R_2\rightarrow R_2-\alpha R_1}\begin{bmatrix} 1& 0\\0&\frac12-\alpha^2\end{bmatrix}.$$
Signature of a matrix is defined as number of positive entries - total no of negative entries.
Signature of matrix of $q$ is $1$ if $\{\displaystyle\alpha\geq\frac{1}{2}\}\cup\{\alpha\leq\frac{-1}{2}\} $.  But there is also another formula so to say viz $2p-r$ where $p$ is the number of positive entries and $r$ is the rank of the diagonal form. For $2p-r=1$ we require $p=1$ and $r=1$. Thus the values of $\alpha=\pm\dfrac{1}{2}$. Is it weird that we are getting two ranges for $\alpha$ for the same quadratic form? I am sure I have made a mistake. Can anyone please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r$ isn't the rank of the matrix. It's the rank of a quadratic form. If the matrix is non-degenerate and $\frac 1 2 - \alpha^2 < 0$ then its signature is $1$.

For definitions see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticFormSignature.html).

Comment: $r$ is the total number of square terms of the quadratic form viz the rank of $\begin{bmatrix} 1& 0\\0&\frac12-\alpha^2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: can we caluculate signature for degenerate quadratic form?

Comment: well, in case of non-degenerate matrices the signature is usually given by tuple $(p, q) \equiv (p, r - p)$, while for degenerate matrices it is described by $(p, q, z)$, where $z$ indicates the number of non-zero $y_{t}$s such that they square to 0. For this case the quadratic form can be written as follows: 
$$
Q = y_1^2 + \dots + y_p^2 - y_{p+1}^2 - \dots - y_{p+q}^2 + y_{p+q+1}^2 + \dots + y_{p+q+z}^2
$$